# Buildroot: change default root shell

Tags: buildroot

We've added bash to our buildroot configuration and would now like to make it the default shell for the root user. I'd prefer not to add a passwd file to our overlay so is there some way through buildroot's config to make the root shell default to /bin/bash rather than /bin/sh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the shell for *all* users to bash by setting `BR2_SYSTEM_BIN_SH_BASH`, i.e. in menuconfig set `System configuration` -> `/bin/sh` to `bash`. This will generate `/bin/sh` as a symlink to `bash`.

To set it for the root user only, you'll need a post-build script such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i '/^root:/s,:/bin/sh$,:/bin/bash,' ${TARGET_DIR}/etc/passwd
```